# Error while loading zone.js and main.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, django, npm

I have a django(1.6.11) project running perfectly fine. I want to use it with Angular2. So, I have been following [this](https://4sw.in/blog/2016/django-angular2-tutorial/) example. I am getting the following error on localhost:8000 page. By the way it shows `Cannot GET /` in localhost:3000.

> Error: Zone$1http://localhost:8000/ng/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:1
>       Zone$1http://localhost:8000/ng/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:114:17
>       scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:8000/ng/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:502:78
>       Zone$1http://localhost:8000/ng/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:1
>       Zone$1http://localhost:8000/ng/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:21
>       drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:8000/ng/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:401:25
>       ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:8000/ng/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:339:25
>
> Evaluating http://localhost:8000/ng/src/main.js   Error loading
>   http://localhost:8000/ng/src/main.js localhost:8000:25

Following a suggestion for a question on stackoverflow, I changed loading `long-stack-trace-zone.js` instead of `zone.js` in my `index.html` code. But this says, `Zone is not defined`. Is this some version compatibility issue? I am using npm 4.1.1 and node v4.8.3. Please do comment if I need to show any of my files.